# Issues with image sizing and browser differences

Tags: html, pug, parallax

I used this code to position a logo (`.logo`) on top of a background (`.bird-box`) and I have an issue with the `.logo`

When I have my logo's actual height as 100px and I use the code below (where the height is set to 100px, everything works great

```
 .bird-box
 position: relative
 height: 800px
 background:
   image: url(../images/background-small.png)
   size: auto 800px
   position: top center
   attachment: fixed
 overflow: hidden

 .logo
  height: 100px
  width: 100%
  background:
    image: url(../images/shardfund.png)
    position: center
    repeat: no-repeat
  position: relative
  top: 50%
  margin-top: -50px
```

RESULT with the above code:
I have two windows where I view the code: In Chrome and in the browser within the Atom (editor).

In the Atom browser: the logo moves with the scroll (when I scroll down, the logo goes up).
Background is static.

In the Chrome browser: the logo moves with the scroll but slower such that when I scroll 800px (the height of the background) the logo disappears. It always stays in the visible background's centre and as the background goes away, so does the logo (apologies if unclear, it's the best verbal explanation I can provide).
P.s. this is actually the desired effect!
I also tested in the code in Firefox (works like in Chrome - perfect)
and in IE10 (works like the Atom explorer - not good!)

### QUESTION: why is there a difference between the Atom and the Chrome browsers and how can it be fixed?

However when I resize my actual logo with a height of 200px and I use the code below, then things are different (explained below).

```
 .bird-box
 position: relative
 height: 800px
 background:
   image: url(../images/background-small.png)
   size: auto 800px
   position: top center
   attachment: fixed
 overflow: hidden

 .logo
  height: 200px
  width: 100%
  background:
    image: url(../images/shardfund.png)
    position: center
    repeat: no-repeat
  position: relative
  top: 50%
  margin-top: -100px
```

After implementing the change, the logo goes to 200px (at least that works) but in regards to movement:
- in Chrome, the logo stays static with the background (not the desired outcome) 
- in the Atom browser it moves with the scroll (not the desired outcome)

QUESTION 1: How can I generally resize the logo and manage to make it stay within the centre of the background until the background disappears during the scrolling (as achieved with the first come in Chrome)

QUESTION 2: How can I make this movement work throughout all browsers?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>BlackBird Co.</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
<header class="bird-box">
  <div class="back-bird"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="fore-bird"></div>
</header>
<section class="content">
  <article>
    <h1>Clothing Store</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </article>
  <!--Make the webpage scrollable-->
  <div style="height: 2000px"> </div>
</section>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, please can you post your html.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. It's posted now.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the logo to remain in a fixed position against the background image?

Comment: No.
The background `.bird-box` is 800px and below that, there's a white slate, so when one scrolls down, it's like this white slate goes above the 800px `.bird-box`. 
I want the logo to be in the centre of the 800px `bird-box`, such that when a person scrolls let's say 400px down, the logo then is in the centre of the 400px background image. Therefore, when the background image disappears, that is when the user has scrolled 800px or more, then the logo disappears with the background.
In short, the logo changes its centre with the scroll. It's always in the centre of the visible top background.

Comment: You are trying to create a fixed element inside a relative container. This is not possible using CSS, as giving an element the fixed attribute removes it from the normal flow of the page; thus it can be in a fixed position relative to the browser only, not the container. Do you have a website as an example of where you have seen this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I do not, however you are correct. I fixed it using the JavaScrip wScroll. I noticed you as well are learning from Codecademy. Good luck and have fun coding. I started there as well!

Comment: Thank you Stelian. All the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually researched further the question myself since posting this and came up with the answer, so here it is:

Using javaScript.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('.logo').css({
'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /2 +'%)'

  })

});
```

Comment: Yes, using JavaScript this is possible. As I mentioned, not possible in with CSS.